# Check if user is flagged in rules

Tags: rules, flags

I want to make a rule that check if the user of the currently **viewed** profile, have flagged the currently **viewing** users profile.

So basicly, have viewing user been flagged by the profile owner of the viewed profile.

So lets say this rule returns true, then there will be a text box when user is viewing profile "This user have flagged you!!".

I have tried all sorts of things in the Data selector of "User who to check" (the field in the buttom of image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Rule with the event "User account page is viewed". Then, you can add the required condition as follows:

[image: Conditions]

So you select the current user as the user that should be Flagged and select the visited user as the person that should have done the Flagging.